# How does one reboot an IBM ds3300?

Tags: network-attached-storage, ibm

We have an [IBM System Storage DS3300 Express SCSI Dual Enclosure Controller Mfr P/N 172632E](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/xbc/cog/storagesystems/ds3300aag.html) that needs to be rebooted.  How does one accomplish this?

Comment: How do you know it needs to be rebooted?

Comment: Because we were having trouble getting into it from the backup server (which is a vm)

Comment: The only way I know is to do ... firmware upgrade. It restarts after deploying new fw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual: ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/46m1393.pdf

You shouldn't reboot it.  Get with IBM if you are having issues with it.  Even the manual states:

> The DS3300 is designed to run continuously. After you turn it on, do
>   not turn it off. Turn off the power only in the following situations:
>   v Instructions in a hardware or software procedure require that you
>   turn off the power. v An IBM technical-support representative
>   instructs you to turn off the power. v A power outage or emergency
>   situation occurs, see “Restoring power after an unexpected shutdown”
>   on page 56. Attention: Except in an emergency, never turn off the
>   power if any amber (needs attention) LEDs are lit. Correct the fault
>   before you turn off the power. Use the DS3000 Storage Manager software
>   and the amber LEDs to check the overall status of the DS3300. All LEDs
>   should be green on the front of the storage subsystem. If they are
>   not, use the DS3000 Storage Manager software to diagnose the problem
>   so that the DS3300 will power-on correctly later.